# Factory girl with Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

Just installed via RVM Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0.  Started a new project and when tried to add the gem 'factory-girl-rails', and run bundle install, I got this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'factory-girl-rails (~> 4.2.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

Any thoughts why can this be happening?

Answer (score 10):

You need to change those dashes to underscores:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
```

Answer (score -2):

factory_girl_rails does not seems to be available for rails higher then version 3.2.11
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails#rails

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I think this was true when you posted. Currently the README is explicit stating "Supported Rails versions are listed in Appraisals". See this file: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/master/Appraisals

Comment: As of today the appraisals file lists support for Rails 3.2, 4.1 and 4.2